# Geektools and Python

Tags: python, macos

I have been playing with Python and geektools and I had the script working before I tided up the code and used loops.

Now it will not display anything past the `lalala` method.

I am working on mac 10.8.1 with geektools 3.0.2.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Simple script that downloads runescape adventures log
#and outputs it to console
# Ashley Hughes 16/SEP/2012

import sys
import urllib2 #For HTTP access
from time import localtime, strftime #Time data functions
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString #XML parser

def lalala(n):
    i = 0
    while(i <= n):
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('description')[i].toxml()
        xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<description>','').replace('</description>','').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
        #print (str(i) + ": " + xmlData)
        print(xmlData)
        i = i + 1

try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen("http://services.runescape.com/m=adventurers-log/rssfeed?searchName=SIG%A0ZerO")
    #f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.runescape.com/")
except Exception, e:
    print "Could not connect"
    sys.exit(1)
s = f.read()
f.close()

dom = parseString(s)

print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime())
print "Working"
lalala(6)
print "Still working"
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: you are probably better off copying the code here.

Comment: you could [edit] your question to include the relevant code inline. What output do you expect? what do you get instead?

Comment: It seems to work fine. Do you mean it does not reach "still working" in your computer?

Comment: It will not work in geektools but it will working in terminal. it prints the date and time and working but does not continue from there

Comment: it worked before I moved it all into the lalala method and cleaned up the code, i dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unicode-ascii problem when your code is 'printing' to GeekTool. Change:

```
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('description')[i].toxml()
```

to this:

```
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('description')[i].toxml().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

this is fine for me in mac 10.8.1 with GeekTool 3.0.3

Look at http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks I had problems with the encoding before, must have for got to fix it when I done the rewrite

Answer (score 0):

That `lalala` method could be tidied up further:

```
def lalala(n):
    i = 0
    while(i <= n):
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('description')[i].toxml()
        xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<description>','').replace('</description>','').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
        #print (str(i) + ": " + xmlData)
        print(xmlData)
        i = i + 1
```

can become

```
def lalala(dom):
    for tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('description'):
        xmlTag = tag.toxml()
        xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<description>','').replace('</description>','').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
        print(xmlData)
```

then you can call it with

```
lalala(dom)
```

instead of `lalala(6)`.

Though, honestly, doing textual tag replacement on XML is probably a bad plan to start with.

Comment: I will look into that but at the moment I only what the last 5 events